# Routing error on ch 2 micropost rails tutorial (routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on the micropost toy_app in [Chapter 2 of the Ruby on Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/toy_app#sec-inheritance_hierarchies), and my site on the cloud9 url (http://rails-tutorial-[username].c9users.io/microposts/new) isn't working. I've tried a bunch of things to try to fix this (eg, ctrl c, starting rails server over, ctrl c again, pushing possible changes I missed to heroku etc), but the displayed web page toggles between the red and white "we're sorry but something went wrong" generic error and the blue/pink floral "No application seems to be running here! Cloud9 can't get you to your requested workspace" errors.

In the C9 dev logs show these two error over and over:
      Rendered /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout

and

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant MicropostsController)

I've searched all over and it looks like most people with routing errors have different errors messages, and it's because they haven't defined their routes properly. I'm totally new to this, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Previously (when I went through chapter 1 of the tutorial), my /users and /users/new pages worked, however now none of those URLs work either. Would this be related to a C9<>bitbucket<>heroku issue, or is it likely to be with my actual code? heroku logs didn't show anything meaningful.

My routes.rb file looks like this:
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :microposts
  resources :users
    root 'microposts#index'
end

For what it's worth, I started the tutorial on 12/25/15, which is the day that rails 2.3 was released-- however my logs show I'm on 2.2.1. I wonder if during the 20-30 hours since I started on 12/25, my rails version on c9 got outdated? I don't understand how that works since I'm using a cloud IDE.

I'm brand new to rails and haven't done any programming aside from a few classes in college-- any tips or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Despite that you should accommodate yourself in how to properly format code at StackOverflow... you wrote a lot but thus very little. If you have a routing error not only your `routes.rb` is the problem but also a file which tries to access something that it cannot yet because the proper route is not installed. This could have several reasons and you did not offer a lot of hints. Nobody here will read any tutorial's text, because without the code you used we could not decide where the error possibly is. :) PS: Routing errors are seldom related to ruby versions themselves.

Comment: It might be just a typo or you forgot to use a rails function on the way to chapter 2, which should have created the proper routes for you. Most of the time it is a form or an URL/link which tries to access a page which is not properly instantiated in the routes file.

Comment: The routes file by the way is very interesting, you can define there where to access what. For example you could name different routes (urls) to access the same content. Like if a house would have two or more doors.

Comment: Thanks for the fast responses! I actually delayed asking my question because I couldn't figure out how to properly format code for StackOverflow, and finally was so stuck I figured posting poorly formatted code was better than nothing :)

Answer (score 0):

After starting over, I finally figured it out after another hour or so-- I had 2 problems. The first was that I'd only run one of the 2 necessary scaffolding commands in the tutorial (doh!). I discovered this by more carefully reading the c9 development log, and noticed a line that said `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/micropost"):`. at this point I realized I was missing the micropost application controller, because I'd never created it with the 2nd scaffolding command: `rails generate scaffold Micropost content:text user_id:integer`

The other problem is that I didn't (and still don't) really understand how the rails server works-- so I was making my changes and not realizing that the server needed to be actively running for the website to load. When I  run the `rails server -b $IP -p $PORT` command, it looks like it never finishes  (eg, the $ for me to start my next command prompt never appears until I hit ctrl c). So I kept hitting ctrl c, not realizing I was killing the server that was hosting the web page.

What I did now was make all my changes, then run the server, then hit ctrl c when I need to make more changes.

Am I doing something wrong with the server stuff? Overall it's working, but it seems like there could be a better way.